# Solving $\arg\max$ problem by calculating gradient of the function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Find $\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{S}^{2}$(unit sphere) such that $$\arg\max_{\mathbf{q}\in\mathbb{S}^{2}}|\mathbf{E}\cdot(\overline{\underline{\mathbf{G}}\cdot \mathbf{q}})|$$ where $\mathbf{E}\in\mathbb{C}^{3}$ and $\underline{\mathbf{G}}\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times3}$ are given data.
>
> ### Here $\overline{\underline{\mathbf{G}}}$ is complex conjugate of $\underline{\mathbf{G}}$. The under line means the matrix

**My attempt**

For $f(\mathbf{q})=|\mathbf{E}\cdot(\overline{\underline{\mathbf{G}}\cdot \mathbf{q}})|$, find $\mathbf{q}$ such that $\nabla_{\mathbf{q}} f(\mathbf{q})=0$.

My question is

(1) is this approach correct?

(2) Since $\mathbf{E}\in\mathbb{C}^{3}$ and  $\underline{\mathbf{G}}\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times3}$ are complex values, should I have to find $\mathbf{q}$ such that 
$Real(\nabla_{\mathbf{q}} f(\mathbf{q}))=0$ and $Image(\nabla_{\mathbf{q}} f(\mathbf{q}))=0$

(3) Can you provide a better approach to me if my attempt is wrong?

Thank you so much.

Comment: So, some vectors are uppercase, others are lowercase?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{S}^2$ here please? Does $\overline{X}$ mean the dual of $X$? Can you explain all notations?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The upper line means the complex conjugate and the underline is just to make a division between vector and matrix.